# OnClick loading background-image from url with timeout or fail function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have an HTML button with an onclick function "clicked()".
If clicked I want to load an image as "background-image" of a div tag.
The image shall be loaded from a server that serves the image very unreliable (rain-radar),
very high answer time up to timeout. I have no control of the server but I am allowed
to fetch the image.

If the image cannot be loaded or is not loaded after 30 seconds I want to show either a failover image or a simple text message to try again later.

I tried to define a second (failover) image url to the style background-image attribute but
then my page always loads the failover image and I guess that's not how it works. Also I dont want to show a "loading image failed" image while page still waits to receive an answer...

index.html

```
...
<a href="#gotoDiv" onclick="clicked()">GoToDiv</a>
...
```

javascript:

```
function clicked(){
    document.getElementById('gotoDiv').style.backgroundImage =  "url('https://UNRELIABLE.SERVER/pic.jpg'), url('/failover.jpg')";
}
```

I there a proper way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a preloading technique

```
function clicked() {

  var elem = document.getElementById('gotoDiv');
  elem.style.backgroundImage = 'url("loading.gif")';

  function setErrorImg () {
    elem.style.backgroundImage = 'url("failover.jpg")';
  }

  var timer = window.setTimeout(setErrorImg, 30000);

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
    elem.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + img.src + '")';
  };
  img.onerror = setErrorImg;
  img.src = 'https://UNRELIABLE.SERVER/pic.jpg';

}
```